# Determine the number of different walks of length 4.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $K_3$ denote the complete graph having 3 vertices. Determine the number of different walks of length 4 there are in $K_3$ from v to v.

So I used a used the induction rule to find the maximum number of edges (I got 6) and drew the graph out. Considering these are walks, reverse and overlapping walks count.

I know I can do this the long way, and go through each walk individually, but I was wondering if there was maybe a simpler much faster way, given that this is a fairly small example and that questions like these can use ridiculously big numbers.

Comment: Why are there $6$ edges?

Comment: Number of edges in K_n = 1/2(n^2-n), proved by induction. I just plugged in the 3. Drawing with the results it looks right. Like a triangle with a loop at each vertex.

Comment: What do you mean by 'loop at each vertex' ? $K_3$ is simply a triangle, hence there are only $3$ edges.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the following interesting result . Let $A$ denote the adjacency matrix of your graph. Then, the $(i,j)$ entry of the matrix $A^n$ will denote the number of walks of length $n$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I set my matrix A as a 3x3 matrix with 1 in every spot, since each vertex can loop back to itself. Setting A^4 gave me 27 walks of length 4.

Comment: A vertex can't loop back to itself, unless you're talking about a pseudograph.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try this.

Consider $K_n$, $k$ steps.

Total number of walks start from $v_1 = (n-1)^k$.

Let $N_i$ denotes the number of walks end at $v_i$. Clearly $\{N_1,...,N_n\}=\{N_1,N_2\}$. Let $N_1=A_k$, $N_2=B_k$.

One can see that $A_k=(n-1) B_{k-1}$, and $B_k=(n-2) B_{k-1}+A_{k-1}=(n-2) B_{k-1}+(n-1)B_{k-2}$.

If loops are not allow (and you can use vertices and edges for more than once), you have

$0$ steps: $1$ walk

$1$ steps: $0$ walk

$2$ steps: $2$ walks

$3$ steps: $2$ walks

$4$ steps: $4$ walks.

Then you can add some loops to the sequence of edges to make it a $4$-walk.

This gives you $1+0+2\times \binom{5}{2}+2 \times \binom{4+1}{4}+4$. Then total number of walks is $1+0+10*2+2*4+4=33$

Comment: Honestly, I'm trying to puzzle out the last part of you're answer(sorry, I'm still learning), but wouldn't that formula for walks starting from v_1 give the right answer? I was counting them out the long way and that was where I could get any more different walks.

Comment: @user316056 For the last part, I thought you want to find out $A_k$, which is number of walks starting from $v_1$ and ending at $v_1$ in $k$ steps. What do you mean by counting them out the long way?

Comment: Yeah sorry I am trying to find that, I just got confused. By long way I mean I started at v_1 and counted out the all the different walks that ended back at v1 in four edges ex:(v_1 e_2 v_2 e_3 v_3 e_5 v_3 e_1 v_1). I was stopping around 16 walks, which was what that formula gives me.

Comment: @user316056 In total you can get $16$ walks. But not all $16$ walks will end at $v_1$. And in fact I don't think loop is considered in complete graph $K_n$...

Comment: @user316056 But if you really want to take loops into account, you can find the total number of walks with $k_0$ steps. For each walk with $k_0$ steps you can just add $k-k_0$ loops into the sequence of edges to make it becomes $k$ steps.

Comment: If that's true since walks can overlapping and go in reverse I thought there would be more than 16 walks, even with length four, that end anywhere besides v_1

Comment: @user316056 Okay so lets count it. If loops are not allow (and you can use vertices and edges for more than once), with $0$ steps: $1$ walk, $1$ steps: $0$ walk, $2$ steps: $2$ walks, $3$ steps: $2$ walks, $4$ steps: $4$ walks. Then you can add $4$ loops to those with $0$ steps, $3$ to those with $1$ step, ... Then this gives you $1+0+2\times \binom{5}{2}+2 \times \binom{4+1}{4}+4$. Then total number of walks is $1+0+10*2+2*4+4=33$

Comment: Wouldn't loops be allowed? I thought I would include them since loops are walks.

Comment: Loops are allowed. I just make use of the case that loops are not allowed to count it.

Comment: I see so the answer wouldnt change. You just added the loops at the end.

Comment: @user316056 Not really. For example, you have two edges already. $1\rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 1$. You can also add loops in middle or at the end, like $1\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 1$ and $1\rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 2\rightarrow 1$