# Number of walks with same start and end of a specific length for directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

How to calculate the total number of walks on a directed graph where the start and end vertex is the same, given a length of the walk.

I tried following the answer from  [Determine the number of different walks of length 4.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663534/determine-the-number-of-different-walks-of-length-4) . From what I understand, it proposes the adjacency matrix to the power of the walk length, but does not consider the same start and end. However, I am not sure I am getting (using numpy) the right answer anyway, given:

```
A= [[0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0]]
```

`A^3` returns

```
[[2, 3, 3],
 [3, 2, 3],
 [3, 3, 2]]
```

Just doing the combinations manually, I get 2 if considering ending on same vertex, and 4 if not.

$v_1 , v_2 , v_1$

$v_1 , v_3 , v_1$

$v_1 , v_2 , v_3$

$v_1 , v_3 , v_2$

To get only the first case (start on v1 and end on v1), how many walks are possible?

Comment: Your manual combinations are not what $A^3$ is determining. The $(i, j)$ entry of $A^k$ is the number of walks of length $k$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$, where the length of a walk is the number of edges (NOT vertices). There are in fact three walks from $v_1$ to $v_3$ of length 3, as the matrix says: $v_1, v_3, v_2, v_3$; $v_1, v_3, v_1, v_3$; and $v_1, v_2, v_1, v_3$.

Comment: @NicholasViggiano if I understand you correctly with 3 edges, then: $v_1,v_2,v_1,v_2$ would also work. Either way, still doesn't solve the issue of it ending on same vertex that it starts.